# How can I boost certain fields over others in elasticsearch?

Tags: boost, elasticsearch, field

My goal is to apply the boost to field "name" (see example below), but I have two problems when I search for "john":

1. search is also matching `{name: "dany", message: "hi bob"}` when name is "dany" and
2. search is not boosting name over message (rows with name="john" should be on the top)

The gist is on https://gist.github.com/tomaspet262/5535774

*(since stackoverflow's form submit returned 'Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code', which was formatted properly).*

Comment: edited to contain ticks (i.e '`') to properly format code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using query time boosting instead of index time boosting.

```
#DELETE
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test'
echo
# CREATE
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test?pretty=1' -d '{
    "settings": {
       "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
               "my_analyz_1" : {
                    "filter" : [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ],
                    "type" : "custom",
                    "tokenizer" : "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# DEFINE
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test/posts/_mapping?pretty=1' -d '{
    "posts" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "my_analyz_1"
            },
            "message" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "analyzer" : "my_analyz_1"
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
# INSERT
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/1 -d '{name: "john", message: "hi john"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/2 -d '{name: "bob", message: "hi john, how are you?"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/3 -d '{name: "john", message: "bob?"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/4 -d '{name: "dany", message: "hi bob"}'
curl localhost:9200/test/posts/5 -d '{name: "dany", message: "hi john"}'
echo
# REFRESH
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/_refresh
echo
# SEARCH
curl "localhost:9200/test/posts/_search?pretty=1" -d '{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "john",
            "fields": ["name^2", "message"]
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is relevant in this case, but when testing with such small amounts of data, I always use 1 shard instead of default settings to ensure no issues because of distributed calculation.